# java.lang.NullPointerException :at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.buildIndexMapping

Tags: java, exception, resultset, multiple-resultsets

I am getting the below exception in my code :

frequent i am getting this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.buildIndexMapping(ResultSet.java:616)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.findColumn(ResultSet.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:5613)
    at com.sfmfm.database.DB_DashBoard.doGet(DB_DashBoard.java:275)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

for this jsp Data not loading properly. browser :firefox latest

if i am running this in eclipse its working fine.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.sfmfm.properties.efmfm;


@WebServlet("/DB_DashBoard")
public class DB_DashBoard extends DB_Conn {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5639866791158510975L;
    static Statement st,st1;

    public DB_DashBoard() throws Exception {
        super();
        st=con.createStatement();
        st1=con.createStatement();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out=response.getWriter();
        String query=request.getParameter("query");

                // create a java calendar instance
                //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                // get a java.util.Date from the calendar instance.
                // this date will represent the current instant, or "now".

        Date now = new Date();

        if(query != null && query.contains("~"))
        {
            System.out.println("Web Browser Request--"+query);
            /*System.out.println("Today Date" +now);        */
            String browser_req[]=query.split("~");





                        if(browser_req[0].equals("Fetch_Pending_Fee"))
                        {

                                StringBuffer AllList = new StringBuffer();

                                try {
                                   ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery("SELECT sm.first_name, sm.last_name, " +
                                        "cs.section_name, cs.class_name, sp.balance_amount, tm.first_name as tfname,tm.last_name as tlname, " +
                                        "sm.contact_no, ft.due_date FROM teacher_master tm,student_master sm," +
                                        " student_payment sp, class_section cs, fee_type ft, student_class sc WHERE" +
                                        " sp.balance_amount!=0 AND sp.student_id = sm.student_id AND" +
                                        " sm.student_id = sc.student_id AND sc.class_id = cs.class_id AND " +
                                        "cs.class_name = ft.class_name AND tm.teacher_id = cs.teacher_id AND ft.fee_type_id=sp.payment_id AND " +
                                        "TO_DAYS(ft.due_date) < TO_DAYS(NOW())");
                                   if (rs != null)
                                    {
                                         while(rs.next())

                                     {
                                         AllList.append("<PENDING>");
                                         AllList.append("<FIRSTNAME>" + rs.getString("first_name") + "</FIRSTNAME>");
                                         AllList.append("<LASTNAME>" + rs.getString("last_name") + "</LASTNAME>");
                                         AllList.append("<CONTACT>" + rs.getString("contact_no") + "</CONTACT>");
                                         AllList.append("<BALANCE>" + rs.getString("balance_amount") + "</BALANCE>");
                                         AllList.append("<DUE>" + rs.getString("due_date") + "</DUE>");
                                         AllList.append("<SECTION>" + rs.getString("section_name") + "</SECTION>");
                                         AllList.append("<CLASS>" + rs.getString("class_name") + "</CLASS>");
                                         AllList.append("<TFNAME>" + rs.getString("tfname") + "</TFNAME>");
                                         AllList.append("<TLNAME>" + rs.getString("tlname") + "</TLNAME>");
                                         AllList.append("<SECTION>" + rs.getString("section_name") + "</SECTION>");
                                         AllList.append("</PENDING>");

                                      }

                                        response.setContentType("text/xml");
                                        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                                        response.getWriter().println("<CATALOG>" + AllList.toString() +"</CATALOG>");

                                        System.out.println("Response sent="+"<CATALOG>" + AllList.toString()+ "</CATALOG>");
                            }

                                }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                            System.out.println("S: Errorhai2");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }



                        }
                        else if(browser_req[0].equals("alert_past_info"))
                        {

                                StringBuffer AllList = new StringBuffer();

                                try {
                                   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT DAY(date_time) AS aday, MONTHNAME(date_time) AS amonth,TIME(date_time) AS atime,title,category,sub_category,details FROM  post_alert ");
                                   if (rs != null)
                                    {
                                          while(rs.next())
                                     {
                                         AllList.append("<PASTALERT>");
                                         AllList.append("<ADAY>" + rs.getInt("aday") + "</ADAY>");
                                         AllList.append("<AMONTH>" + rs.getString("amonth") + "</AMONTH>");
                                         AllList.append("<ATIME>" + rs.getInt("atime") + "</ATIME>");
                                         AllList.append("<ATITLE>" + rs.getString("title") + "</ATITLE>");
                                         AllList.append("<ACATA>" + rs.getString("category") + "</ACATA>");
                                         AllList.append("<ASUB>" + rs.getString("sub_category") + "</ASUB>");
                                         AllList.append("<ADESC>" + rs.getString("details") + "</ADESC>");
                                         AllList.append("</PASTALERT>");
                                      }
                                        response.setContentType("text/xml");
                                        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                                        response.getWriter().println("<CATALOG>" + AllList.toString() +"</CATALOG>");

                                        System.out.println("Response sent="+"<CATALOG>" + AllList.toString()+ "</CATALOG>");
                            }

                                }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                            System.out.println("Error On Past Alert Viewing");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }



        }
}


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

pls provide the suggestions to clear this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is coming from mysql driver. Your classpath in eclipse may use a different driver version that the one you are using once your app is deployed. It probably explain why you never get this error when running in eclipse.

So I suggest you to check the driver version your are using (and probably upgrading the one you use when the app is deployed).

Comment: i am using the same mysql-connector-java-5.0.5-bin eclipse. after running this code in eclipse browser its working normally even firefox. problem is when i am first time loading in firefox.